# Android Sub Menu Changes Background Color

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android application that I want to add a sub menu for. The background of the application is the default which is black. All of the text on the app is white which I also think is the default. So I added in the sub menu but when I click on the sub menu the background turns to white but the text doesn't turn to black.

Any idea why the default sub menu behavior isn't working correctly? I'm hoping not to have to create styles and all that and the solution will be fairly simple.

Comment: It's odd, why don't you just specify background and text color to the colors you want?

Comment: just a simple 
`android:backround="#000"` in the parent view.
and
`android:textColor="#fff"` to the text stuff

Comment: So set that background and text color inside the intent view?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I would think this sub menu would just work by default a lot like the context menus.

Comment: My requirement no longer needs this to be an option in the menu. So I will not be adding it which makes this problem mute. This seems to be like a core android problem though. Seems like a lot of others are running into the same issue. There looks to be no really good solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. This was due to me using titleCondensed instead of just using title. For some reason on sub menus it needs to use title but on the regular menu it works fine. Programming mistake by me.